# Как переместить в другое место нарисованный объект-картинку "r1" Python через библиотеку Pygame, при этом удалив картинку с прошлого места?

Tags: python, pygame

Выводит ошибку:

```
a = event.pos()
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Если в этом куске программы надо совершенно по-другому написать код, пожалуйста, напишите, как надо написать.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1273, 720))
board = pygame.image.load("Images/board.png")
window.blit(board, (0, 0))
r1 = pygame.image.load("Images/red_checker.png")

def first_step(a):
    window.blit(r1, (a))

count_step = 0
run = True
while run:

    if count_step == 0:
        first_step(r1, (30, 480))
    else:
        first_step(r1, (a))
        count_step += 1

    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            a = event.pos()
            first_step(a)
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что кто-то другой должен переписать ваш код?

Comment: @СергейКох, если кому-то будет не сложно написать как нужно, то я буду очень рад. Так как при написании программы застрял, и не знаю как написать правильно то, что я хочу увидеть.

Comment: У вас первая ошибка, при вызове функции first_step(r1, (30, 480)), вас обучали как правильно вызывать функцию?

Comment: @СергейКох, понял, я сейчас исправил у себя её. Можете пожалуйста сказать какая следующая ошибка?

Comment: Включайте отладчик и вперед!

Comment: @СергейКох, я включил, прошёлся по коду, у меня программа зависает перед строчкой, где ошибка (даже до неё), а сама строчка с ошибкой не обрабатывается. Подскажите, что делать в таком случае?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pygame import *

# window = display.set_mode((1273, 720))
window = display.set_mode((0, 0), FULLSCREEN)

bg = image.load("Images/board.png")
r1 = image.load("Images/red_checker.png")

run = True
while run:

    window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    window.blit(dg, (0, 0))

    window.blit(r1, (тут позиция)) # # # # #

    display.update()

    for event in event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = mouse.get_pos()
            # функция?
display.quit()
```

суть в очищении всего экрана и заново нарисовоного r1